# Unity3D - Cannot Share Screenshot to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, share, screenshot

I am trying to share screenshot image to facebook using unity3D. I am able to login to Facebook through Unity, and after login I am able to access my profile pic.

Now I want to take a screenshot of my app and share it to facebook. I did this using the following code which I took from facebook's developer's page:

```
private IEnumerator TakeScreenshot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "Screenshot.png");

    FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, AuthCallback, wwwForm);
}
```

But I'm getting the result as "403 Forbidden". What am I doing wrong here? Or is there any other way to share a screenshot to facebook using Unity.

Any help will be appreciated.

Prabha.

Comment: Do you have post permission?

Comment: @Faisal Khalid, I don't have post permission, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to make sure.

**1**.Make sure you have [publish permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions).

**2**.If you have publish permission then build the project and run it on a physical Android device. Once you run it, you will then be able to [make](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/735264/view.html) it post screenshot from the Editor.